# Multiplicity in restriction of representations

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Let $H\subset G$ be groups. Let $\pi$ be an irreducible complex representation of $G$ and let $\sigma$ be an irreducible complex representation of $H$. The multiplicity of $\sigma$ in the restriction of $\pi$ to $H$ is $$\dim \operatorname{Hom}_H(\sigma,\pi).$$

Sometimes in the literature, I see the notation $$\dim \operatorname{Hom}_{H} (\pi\otimes \sigma,\mathbf{C})$$

where $H$ is diagonally embedded in $G\times H$.

In which cases are those two equal ?

I think that $\operatorname{Hom}_H(\pi\otimes \sigma,\mathbf{C})=\operatorname{Hom}_H(\pi,\sigma^\vee)$, so when $\sigma$ is self-dual, it is the case.

[This paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1209.2798) says that if $F$ is a non-archimedean local field of residue characteristic $\neq 2$, then an irreducible (admissible) representation of a (special) orthogonal group $O(V)$ or $SO(V)$ is self-dual.

Are there any other cases ? What can be said about this in general ?

Any help is appreciated.